# Color of all views changed when added dynamically

Tags: android, view

I have added some views to linear layout dynamically within for loop

LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/abc"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="vertical"/>
```

Added View using inflate:

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_action_icon"
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_action_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv_action_icon"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_rightgo"
    android:textSize="17sp"/>

  <View
    android:id="@+id/v_line"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.5dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/iv_action_icon"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv_action_icon"
    android:background="@color/line_grey"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Added view has a line (v_line). I have to change the color of that after the for loop.

I do something like this.

```
  View lastView = llGroup.getChildAt(llGroup.getChildCount() -1);
if(lastView != null){
View lineLastView = lastView.findViewById(R.id.v_line);
lineLastView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
}
```

But this change the color of lines of all added views instead of last one.

Comment: Post the code of xml also.

Comment: What for loop are you talking about?

Comment: @AnuragSingh Update

Comment: @MehmetKologlu "for loop" in which multiple views added dynamically.

Comment: I still don't see it... why dont you share that with us as well

Comment: I believe it will be easier if you share the code completely.

Comment: @Ajit just a wild guess but try to change the last line color with some delay may be some 200 or 300 ms

Comment: @d1vivek681065 Thanks its working :)